# Unity3d - APK is compatible only on 200 devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

I have a simple game that I developed on Unity3D platform. The game uses only one plugin in order to get access to the phone temperature, gyro, accelerometer and more.

The app is running on various devices, I installed the app manually on them. Also, I'm able to make a build and generate an APK via Unity. The problem is that when I uploaded my new APK to the Google play store, I got a message telling me that my app is supported only on about 200 Android devices. Without the plugin, I was able to get/give support for about 10,000 devices.

I tried to change the AndroidManifest that came with the plugin, but with no luck. I only want to use 4 permissions and 8 features that are quite common:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
android.hardware.sensor.ACCELEROMETER
android.hardware.sensor.AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE
android.hardware.sensor.COMPASS
android.hardware.sensor.GYROSCOPE
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: could it be the AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE sensor request? I think thats a pretty unusual request. could be only 200 devices have that.

Comment: Yes, removing AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE did the trick! Now my app can run on about 4,080 Android devices. Thank you.